# Spring native - CustomAuthenticationManager (ReactiveAuthenticationManager)

Tags: spring-security, spring-native

I am not able to make the native image work. I have my custom Reactive Authentication Manager and everything works fine when I run the service with mvn spring-boot:run. But when I create the container with the native image, and I run it, I get the following error:

```
webflux-netty_1  | java.lang.IllegalStateException: No provider found for class com.example.webflux.security.JwtAuthenticationToken
webflux-netty_1  |      at org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.lambda$authenticate$6(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:123) ~[na:na]
webflux-netty_1  |      Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
webflux-netty_1  | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
webflux-netty_1  |      |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
webflux-netty_1  |      |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
```

I cannot find any example with this. Could anyone help please?

Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: It's possible you are using a feature that is not yet supported in Spring Native. If you create an issue in the Spring Native GitHub repository with a minimal, reproducible example, we can take a look at it there. https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was a stupid mistake I did, I have realised about it cause I got the same error running in from IntelliJ IDEA. Sorry for that. Closing the question.